# Retrofit работа с HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, https, retrofit

Работаю с Retrofit2, при попытке обратиться к протоколу https он начинает ругаться, как мне подключить к нему сертификат? На просторах интернета находил код что-то вроде:

```
OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient();
okHttp.setSslSocketFactory(getSSLConfig(contex).getSocketFactory());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(okHttp).build();
retrofit.create(serviceClass)
```

Я подключал `OkHttp` но...метода `setSslSocketFactory` там не обнаружил.

P.S. Подключал OkHttp из:

> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'

Исходники:

```
 Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://site.cf")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder().add("site.cf","sha256/key").build();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
```

Comment: Не оно? https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html

Comment: Добавил исходники, подключив сертификат всё равно получаю  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: а сертификат не самоподписаный случаем?

Comment: C cамозаверенными сертификатами такое не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

посмотрите в сторону CustomTrust что-то там(с телефона пишу, сложно искать :) в библиотеке okhttp3. И гуглите как его юзать для selfsigned

PS блин, как ответ запостилось...

Comment: Если сертификат будет подтвержден, заработает ли тот код который я написал выше в исходниках?

Comment: Либо не имеет значения кем подтвержден сертификат?

Comment: Подписание сертификата увы не помогло

Comment: Вы были правы, загуглив CustomTrust наткнулся на статью с реализацией метода который помог http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716001/how-to-post-https-request-using-retrofit